# planar graph of Submultiples

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

There is Graph which is connected with Submultiples. (I am sorry but I don't know what this is called.)

For example,

10-node Graph has 10 nodes, 18 edges. node 1 connect all the other nodes. node 2 connect node number 2,4,6,8,10. node 3 connect 3,6,9. node 4 connect 4,8. etc.
[Image of Planar graph of 10-node Submultiple graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAHFk.png) This is Planar graph of 10-node graph.

[image]

### Question 1.

It is easy to check if 11-node graph is planar or not. (Just put the node no.11 and connect with no.1) But, **Is 12-node Submultiple graph planar?** And how can I prove it? (I saw [Kuratowski's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_theorem) But I cannot find the graph of $K_{3,3}$ If there is, please show me with picture.

### Question 2.

If 12-node Submultiple graph is possible, How many node are possible? (I mean, 14 or 15 nodes graph is planar? or not?)

Comment: I think the word you're looking for is "divisors."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a planar graph for $12$ nodes:

[image]

The thicker red edges are the onesthat I changed their orientations. Green edges are the ones that are incident to node $12$.

From here, I can say that for $13$ and $14$ nodes, it can be still planar. $13$ is similar to $11$ since $13$th node is just adjacent to $1$ and for $14$, we can add $14$ to outer face in which $2$ and $7$ reside.

For $15$, it is not trivial. But there is a $K_{3,3}$ subgraph using subdivions as the following:

[image]

Then by Kuratowski's Theorem, it is not planar.

For $16$ nodes, I am sure that it cannot be planar because the nodes $1,2,4,8,16$ will all be connected to each other so we have $K_5$ as a subgraph. Then by Kuratowski's Theorem, it is not planar.